# when i am trying to print a json result using alamofire with swift 4 i am getting an "Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=303"

Tags: ios, alamofire, swift4, xcode9

```
Alamofire.request("https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlists", 
method: .get, parameters: ["part": "snippet", "channelId": 
"UCMztOaBEOOswwu0wHlchkeA", "key": 
"AIzaSyBHzTMlp1FkiIQJxda5UgSunikzfnQWnwQ" ], encoding: 
JSONEncoding.default, headers: nil).downloadProgress(queue: 
DispatchQueue.global(qos: .utility)) { Progress in
        print("progress: \(Progress.fractionCompleted)")

                }
        .validate { request ,response ,data in


            return .success
    }

        .responseJSON { response in
            print(response)
            debugPrint(response)
    }
```

when i am trying to print the response i am getting error "Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=303

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `JSONEncoding.default` to `URLEncoding.default`

These parameters are query parameters defined [here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlists/list), thus you should use `URLEncoding` instead of `JSONEncoding`